# How to inject repository in the application class using dagger (GithubBrowserSample)?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-architecture-components

I want to implement authentication in my application, so I want to get the current logged user in the application class, I am following [GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) to develop my application, but I am very new to dagger injection and I am a little lost in how to inject my authRepository to my application class.

```
class App : Application(), HasActivityInjector {
    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
        }
        AppInjector.init(this)
    }

    override fun activityInjector() = dispatchingAndroidInjector

}
```

I tried adding something like

```
@Inject 
lateinit var authRepository: AuthRepository
```

in the application class and in the AppModule

```
//I already have functions that provide everything the repository needs
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideAuthRepository(
        appExecutors: AppExecutors,
        db: AppDatabase,
        trainersService: TrainersService,
        sessionDao: SessionDao,
        tokenInterceptor: TokenInterceptor
): AuthRepository {
    return AuthRepository(
            appExecutors,
            db,
            trainersService,
            sessionDao,
            tokenInterceptor
    )
}
```

but it throws Uninitialized Property Access Exception

Hope you can help me to achive this following the github sample approach.

Comment: This AuthRepository class, did you annotate it with @Inject? Or did you create a provider method for letting Dagger know how to create it?

Comment: I only used the @Inject Annotation

Comment: Can you post your component ?